# Makefile substituting special characters

Tags: replace, makefile, special-characters, substitution

I want to change an **%** by a **?** or vise versa. Neither of the following works, the original string is not changed.

```
varStrg1=this/is_a/%_test
test=$(subst \%,\?,$(varStrg1))
test=$(patsubst \%,\?,$(varStrg1))

varStrg2=this/is_a/?_test
test=$(subst \?,\%,$(varStrg2))
test=$(patsubst \?,\%,$(varStrg2))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't escape things with backslashes in makefiles (at least, not within function invocations).  You're trying to replace the literal string `\%` with the literal string `\?` and since your string doesn't contain any `\%` character combinations, nothing happens.

For `subst` you can just use them directly:

```
test = $(subst %,?,$(varStrg1))

test = $(subst ?,%,$(varStrg2))
```

The only characters special in a `subst` function are `$`, `,`, and `)` I believe.

For `patsubst`, you can't use it for this purpose.

Comment: Right, it worked. I am surprised that I was so focus on removing its meaning with a back slash and on using the wrong function (patsubst) that I did not see the obvious. Thanks.